# I have a column of characters that I can't use when creating visuals: I have tried multiple transformations and nothing is working. Please Assist

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm on day two of working with an awesome Chi-Sqr analysis. I have all my data cleaned my matrices and dfs created...the tests run....however I am having a heck of a time trying to create the visualizations.
[The Frequency Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyqJD.jpg)

Some of the code I've been running:

> M <- cor(Top25.ForVIZ)
>       *Error in cor(Top25.ForVIZ) : 'x' must be numeric*

```
> M.4.viz <- as.table(as.matrix(Top25.ForVIZ))
> M <- cor(M.4.viz)
*Error in cor(M.4.viz) : 'x' must be numeric*

> corrplot::corrplot(M.4.viz)
*Error in corrplot::corrplot(M.4.viz) : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!*
> head(Top25.ForVIZ)
[Header For Data][1]
> cormat <- round(cor(Top25.ForVIZ),2)
*Error in cor(Top25.ForVIZ) : 'x' must be numeric*
> topic_name <- as.factor(Top25.ForVIZ$topic_name)
> str(Top25.ForVIZ)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   25 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ topic_name                          : chr  "Accenture (ACN)" "Amazon (AMZN)" "Belgacom (PROX)" "Checking Account" ...
 $ TTL.Score.Pre.Disconnect.3.week.cons: num  1489 1519 1833 2441 1560 ...
 $ Active.Segment.1                    : num  1166 2115 1024 2383 2931 ...
 $ TTL.Score.3.Week.Post.Diconnect     : num  1546 1712 1401 1683 1587 ...

> cormat <- round(cor(Top25.ForVIZ),2)
*Error in cor(Top25.ForVIZ) : 'x' must be numeric*

> topic_name <- as.numeric(Top25.ForVIZ$topic_name)
*Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion* 
> str(Top25.ForVIZ)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   25 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ topic_name                          : chr  "Accenture (ACN)" "Amazon (AMZN)" "Belgacom (PROX)" "Checking Account" ...
 $ TTL.Score.Pre.Disconnect.3.week.cons: num  1489 1519 1833 2441 1560 ...
 $ Active.Segment.1                    : num  1166 2115 1024 2383 2931 ...
 $ TTL.Score.3.Week.Post.Diconnect     : num  1546 1712 1401 1683 1587 ...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGdHh.jpg
```

My end goal is to be able to work with the data in corplots, ggplot etc...I also would like to understand from a logic perspective what I am doing wrong.

TIA.

Comment: What if you simply exclude your non-numeric column (variable) and re-run your code with just your numeric variables? If you do `?cor` you'll see that the input `x` should be numeric (vector, matrix or data frame).

Comment: Yes, that works. However when I go to create visuals I have no titles. I'd really like my visuals to be labeled for presentation purposes.

Comment: What type of visuals? Which function do you want to use? You want as labels the columns names or the values of the variable you removed?

Comment: I'm using corplots and ggplot, I want the names of the variables in the frequency table in the visualizations. I do not want the numeric label of each observation. Exp. Column 1 consists of 25 internet sites, Column 2, 3, 4 consists of frequency values -> I want to create a correlation plot without losing the labels from Column 1.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to use those values in Column 1 in a correlation plot. That plot calculates the correlations between your (numeric) columns, so it will use the column names (like this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html). If you have something else in mind you have to post what you've tried and how you want your plot to be.

Comment: It was a data.frame issue. My row names were not my actual row names. Thank you for all your help.